# Are those 2 questions asking about the same thing?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hamel-basis

Here is the first question:

Let $X$ and $Y \neq \{0\}$ be normed spaces, where $dim X = \infty.$ Show that there is at least one unbounded linear operator $T: X \rightarrow Y.$ (Use a Hamel basis.)

Here is the second question:

Let $X$ be a normed linear space that is not finite dimensional. Prove that there exists an unbounded linear functional on $X.$

Are those 2 questions asking about the same thing? If not how they are different?

I am asking this because I know the answer to the first question and I want to use it to answer the second question.

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution to the first question:

> Solution
>
> Let $H$ be an Hamel basis for $X$ (see theorem $4.1-7$ ). We will show that any function $T: H \rightarrow Y$ can be extended to a linear operator $\tilde{T}: X \rightarrow Y$ Let $x$ be in $X .$ since $H$ is an Hamel basis, $\exists x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ in $H$ and scalars $\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}$ such that $x=\alpha_{1} x_{1}+\ldots+\alpha_{n} x_{n} .$ So define
> $$
> \tilde{T}(x)=\alpha_{1} T\left(x_{1}\right)+\ldots+\alpha_{n} T\left(x_{n}\right)
> $$
> Definition is well-defined since any element $x$ in $X$ has unique representation wrt
> $H . \tilde{T}$ is linear because if $x, y \in X$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are scalars (say $x=\alpha_{1} x_{1}+\ldots+\alpha_{n} x_{n}$ and $\left.y=\beta_{1} y_{1}+\ldots+\beta_{k} y_{k} \text { wrt } H\right)$ then
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \tilde{T}(\alpha x+\beta y) &=\tilde{T}\left(\alpha\left(\alpha_{1} x_{1}+\ldots+\alpha_{n} x_{n}\right)+\beta\left(\beta_{1} y_{1}+\ldots+\beta_{k} y_{k}\right)\right) \\
> &=\tilde{T}\left(\alpha \alpha_{1} x_{1}+\ldots+\alpha \alpha_{n} x_{n}+\beta \beta_{1} y_{1}+\ldots+\beta \beta_{k} y_{k}\right) \\
> &=\alpha \alpha_{1} T\left(x_{1}\right)+\ldots+\alpha \alpha_{n} T\left(x_{n}\right)+\beta \beta_{1} T\left(y_{1}\right)+\ldots+\beta \beta_{k} T\left(y_{k}\right) \\
> &=\alpha\left[\alpha_{1} T\left(x_{1}\right)+\ldots+\alpha_{n} T\left(x_{n}\right)\right]+\beta\left[\beta_{1} T\left(y_{1}\right)+\ldots+\beta_{k} T\left(y_{k}\right)\right] \\
> &=\alpha \bar{T}(x)+\beta \bar{T}(y)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Lets turn the question. since $H$ is an infinite set let $v_{1}, v_{2}, \ldots$ be in $H .$ Fix non-zero $y \in Y .$ Define the function $T: H \rightarrow Y$ by $T\left(v_{n}\right)=n\left\|v_{n}\right\| y$ and $\mathbf{0}$ otherwise. Then $T$ can be extended to a linear operator $\tilde{T}: X \rightarrow Y .$ But $\tilde{T}$ can not be bounded, given $c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ choose $n>c /\|y\|$, so $\left\|\tilde{T} v_{n}\right\|=n\left\|v_{n}\right\|\|y\|>c\left\|v_{n}\right\|$

Comment: They are not asking about the same thing. In the first question $Y$ can be any normed space. In the second, it $Y$ has to be the base field (which is also a normed space)

Comment: So I will include the solution of the first question and could you please tell me how can I modify it to answer the second question .... ok?@G.Chiusole

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) is a normed space, then the second question is a special case of the first one.

Comment: Yes I know this in general @G.Chiusole

Comment: Well then the second question is just a special case of the first.

Comment: @G.Chiusole I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second question is different from the first one, since a linear functional on $X$ is a linear operator from $X$ into $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$). So, in principle, there might be such an example for the first question, and not to exist an example for the second one (that's not the case though).

Comment: So can I include the solution to the first one in my question above and then could you please tell me how can I modify this solution to solve the second one or even tell me if this solution does not work at all for the second one .... ok?

Comment: You can do that, but I fail to see the point of it. If, in your example, $Y$ is the base field, then your example will also work for the second question. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your second sentence? The second question is just a special case of the first

Comment: Yes, it is. And therefore, every example that works for the second question will also work for the first one. But not the other way around.

Comment: I see - thank you

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Is this **your** answer? I ask this because it **really** looks as if it was taken from some textbook or lecture notes.

Comment: yes it is taken from solutions to a book .... is it fine as an answer for the second question?

Comment: Yes, if $Y$ is the base field. No, otherwise.

Comment: So, can  I put this extra assumption on the solution? I can see that the solution does not depend on anything in $Y$ ..... am I correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: I do not understand the last part of the solution (the last paragraph ) what is the author doing and why ? Is the solution of the question has 2 directions?